# autocomplete textbox are not working in ci

Tags: codeigniter

controller: Test.php

```
<?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
    class Test extends CI_Controller 
    {
        function __construct() 
        {
            parent :: __construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
            $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
        }
        public function index()
        {
            $searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
            $data['search'] = $this->Fetch_data->autocomplete($searchTerm);
            $this->load->view('index',$data);          
        }
    }
```

view: index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="colleges" id="colleges" class="form-control" />
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#colleges" ).autocomplete({
            source: '<?php echo base_url("index.php"); ?>/test/index';
        });
    });
</script>
```

model: Fetch_data.php

```
<?php  
    class Fetch_data extends CI_Model  
    {  
        function __construct()  
        {   
            parent::__construct();  
        }  
        public function autocomplete($searchTerm)
        {
            $this->db->select('college_name,field');
            $this->db->from('all_colleges');
            $where = "short_name like '%".$searchTerm."%' or college_name like '%".$searchTerm."%'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $this->db->order_by('college_name');
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```

I am new in ci. Using this code I want to create a autocomplete suggestion box in codeigniter But this code is not work for me. So, how can I create autocomplete suggestion box in ci and please tell me what wrong in my code can I use this code for autocompletion.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED** You can try this:

in you Model **Fetch_data.php**

```
<?php  
class Fetch_data extends CI_Model  
{  
    function __construct()  
    {   
        parent::__construct();  
    }  
    public function autocomplete()
    {
        $this->db->select('college_name,field');
        $this->db->from('all_colleges');
        $this->db->order_by('college_name');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

controller: **Test.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Test extends CI_Controller 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->model('Fetch_data');
    }
    public function index()
    {
        $all_data = array();
        $result  = $this->Fetch_data->autocomplete(); //collect all college name
        foreach($result as $key=>$value){
           array_push($all_data, $value["college_name"]);
        }

        $data['search'] = $all_data;
        $this->load->view('index',$data);          
    }
}
```

view: **index.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="colleges" id="colleges" class="form-control" />
<input type='hidden' id='mydata' value='<?php echo json_encode($search);?>' />
<script>

    $( function() {
       var oData = $("#mydata").val();
           oData = JSON.parse(oData);
       $( "#colleges" ).autocomplete({
          source: oData;
       }); 
    });
</script>
```

You can get all the college_names and store it with a variable then when you enter a letter you can no longer use ajax because it is already stored with a variable.

Hope it will work.

Comment: it showing warning error i.e. undefine index: term @Nelson Estuesta Jr

Comment: I updated my answer.. I forgot to remove the `$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];` on the controller. you can try it again.

Comment: when I use print_r($data['search']); it display all colleges name but when I write anything on my textbox name="colleges" it display nothing @Nelson

Comment: Can you `console.log(oData);` inside function() in your script. just like this to test if your oData variable is not empty. `$(function() { console.log(oData);
        $( "#colleges" ).autocomplete({
            source: oData;
        });
    });`

Comment: see what am i doing:    <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     var oData = '<?php echo $search;?>';
     $(function() { 
      console.log(oData); 
      $( "#colleges" ).autocomplete({ 
       source: oData; 
      }); 
     });
 }); 
</script>

Comment: Yes thats right. Is there any value of the `oData` on your console?

Comment: Oh I got it now... i will update my answer please check it.

Comment: in which file @Nelson

Comment: Thank You @Nelson You help me a lot